# QWidget not displaying the QLabel

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QWidget which I want to use like a Dialog on top of another QWidget.

What I'm trying to do is a simple "Please wait while yadda yadda..." dialog with no buttons.

The code section is as follows:

```
void NewWindow::on_combobox_New_currentIndexChanged(int index) //slot function
{
    QWidget* box = new QWidget();
    box->setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
    box->setWindowTitle("Wait...");

    QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout();
    box->setLayout(layout);
    QLabel* lbl = new QLabel();
    lbl->setText("Loading...");
    layout->addWidget(lbl);

    box->show();


    for (int var = 0; var < st.size(); ++var)
    {
        //Some heavy lifting here
    }

    box->close();
}
```

Normally I would expect this dialogue box to appear with the proper text and disappear after the loop ends. In fact it does that too but with one difference: The label does not display. The widget looks empty. Then disappears.

[image: QWidget label not displaying]

If I copy the code into a different area (for example to the MainWindow constructor) it displays properly with the message in it.

[image: QWidget label displaying properly]

I sense that the loop blocks the draw operation but then the widget itself should be missing too. Why it is only the label eludes me.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: What's in the `for (int var =` loop?  Do you ever process events?

Comment: You never set the widget layout. You specified box as the parent in the layout constructor, but I still think you have to do box->setLayout(layout).

Comment: @G.M., I have no business with events, at least not as far as I know. I produce some `QTableWidgetItem` s and insert them into a totally different `QTableWidget` .

Comment: But where your box object gets attached to the layout .. solve this issue first

Comment: @Marker , you may have a point, but it's exactly the same code that produces the different result in Main Window constructor. And also I tried `setLayout` too, made no difference.

Comment: have you tried adding `QCoreApplication::processEvents();` inside the loop? (where you have *heavy processing*). Without calling `processEvents` you never pass control back to the Qt event loop to actually do the drawing you've requested of it

Comment: if you remove `box->close()` from your combo box event handler, does the widget display properly once the "heavy lifting" is complete?

Comment: @SteveLorimer , that did the trick. Thank you very much for the new perspective. I would appreciate it more if you can explain the dynamics involved in an answer, and let me accept it as "the answer" :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are creating and displaying this widget in a QObject slot, and then before returning from the slot, closing the widget, by the time Qt goes through the process of executing all your instructions, the last one is `close`, and so the widget disappears from view.

Underneath your slot, Qt is running in an event loop. Since control is never returned to the event loop, Qt never has an opportunity to render the graphics you've requested of it.

When you create widgets, add labels, etc, you are actually registering a bunch of commands with the event loop, which will only later be processed.

If you want Qt to render any changes you have made **whilst in a slot**, before returning to the event loop, you have to call [`processEvents`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents).

Without doing so, you won't see those changes *until control passes back to the Qt event loop*.

So what is happening here, is that since you're also **closing** the widget at the end of your slot, Qt will create the widget, render its contents, and then immediately close it, and you won't see anything.

The reason for this is so that Qt can do calculations on what is visible, what isn't, be smart about what it renders  etc, and only decide to draw what is necessary.

If it just rendered everything immediately, without waiting for control to return to it so it can process the "next batch of updates", it would likely be horribly inefficient.

So you need to put `processEvents` inside your callback slot.

```
void NewWindow::on_combobox_New_currentIndexChanged(int index) //slot function
{
    QWidget* box = new QWidget();
    box->setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
    box->setWindowTitle("Wait...");

    QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout();
    box->setLayout(layout);
    QLabel* lbl = new QLabel();
    lbl->setText("Loading...");
    layout->addWidget(lbl);

    box->show();
    QCoreApplication::processEvents(); // cause the box to be displayed

    for (int var = 0; var < st.size(); ++var)
    {
        //Some heavy lifting here

        // if you do anything here to change the widget, such as 
        // updating a progress bar, you need to `processEvents` again

        QCoreApplication::processEvents();
    }

    box->close();
}
```

As for why the widget window appears, but not the contents, this is likely because when creating the widget Qt sends a message to the Window Manager (in this case MS Windows), which will create the window on which Qt can render its contents.

So you see the result of Windows creating a new window for Qt, but nothing from Qt painting on that window itself.

Comment: Very nice explanation, thank you very much. I was not aware of the necessity of the `processEvents` while in a slot. That is a critical piece of information for me.

Comment: @DoğukanTunç *normally* you don't need to call `processEvents` in a slot - typically you'd want to leave it up to Qt to decide when to do that. It is only if you want to **force** Qt to update the view *whilst in a slot* that you do so. I added some text to my answer on *why* Qt does it this way which might be useful

Comment: I see. If you have to update the GUI thread while in a **slot**, _then_ you need to call this method. Actually, I was pulling some "insert items into the QTableWidget" code inside loop. When I added the `processEvents` into the loop, now I can witness the items being pushed into the table too :)

Comment: @DoğukanTunç You should generally avoid using things like `processEvents`. This can cause all kinds of problems in your application, if you're not careful.